# Convert Jasper .jrxml to Microsofts .rdlc

Tags: c#, java, jasper-reports, rdlc

I have a huge (literally in the hundreds) number of reports made in Jasper and saved in .jrxml format. Now, we are migrating some parts of our application to C#, and we need those reports. Our prefered solution would be to convert them to .rdlc and use Microsoft's native solution for reporting.

Is this possible? Or would we be forced to remake them all?

And before anyone suggests it, yes, we can call Java code to print reports. That is our temporary solution at the moment, but this is clunky and error prone, and we are trying to scrap java code from our base anyway, so we are looking for a long term solution.

Answer (score 1):

Jasper and Microsoft Reports use quite different models for the reports. I created reports for both products already. Converting from Jasper is hardly possible automatically. The way for example tables are made is completely different. You will have to do the conversion by hand. You will also face the challenge of missing features which Jasper offers and Microsoft doesn't.

For what its worth in my opinion Jasper is the more powerful and flexible solution.